# How to use for loop to check for winner in tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to build a javascript tic tac toe game and I'm at the point where I need to check if there is a winner. Instead of writing redundant code, which I believe I'm starting to do. How can I check for a winner using a for loop without having to write redundant code?

```
<div id="board">
  <div class="row">
    <div data-n=1 class="sq sq-1"></div>
    <div data-n=2 class="sq sq-2"></div>
    <div data-n=3 class="sq sq-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div data-n=4 class="sq sq-4"></div>
    <div data-n=5 class="sq sq-5"></div>
    <div data-n=6 class="sq sq-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div data-n=7 class="sq sq-7"></div>
    <div data-n=8 class="sq sq-8"></div>
    <div data-n=9 class="sq sq-9"></div>
  </div>
</div>




//using counter to alternate player
var counter = 0;
var currentPlayer;

$('.sq').on('click', function() {
  if (!this.innerHTML) {
    if (counter % 2 === 0) {
      this.innerHTML = '0';
      currentPlayer = '0';
    } else {
      this.innerHTML = 'X';
      currentPlayer = 'X';
    }  
  counter++;
 } 

  //check if there is a winner here
  if ($('.sq-1').html() == currentPlayer && 
      $('.sq-2').html() == currentPlayer &&
      $('.sq-3').html() == currentPlayer) {
      console.log(currentPlayer + ' wins');
   };
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/payam10/6qzu7L4f/4/

Comment: This post is most likely going to be removed because it really is asking for opinions, rather than a specific question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I edited it

Comment: For html standards, you should enclose your data-n values in quotes... `data-n="1"`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips data-* attribute values will validate without quotes as long as the value does not contain a space or otherwise illegal chars. This is the case with all HTML attribute values in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

There are only 8 ways to win in tic-tac-toe, so I'd probably just do something simple like:

```
<div id="board">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sq sq-1 win-1 win-4 win-7"></div>
    <div class="sq sq-2 win-1 win-5"></div>
    <div class="sq sq-3 win-1 win-6 win-8"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sq sq-4 win-2 win-4"></div>
    <div class="sq sq-5 win-2 win-5 win-7 win-8"></div>
    <div class="sq sq-6 win-2 win-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sq sq-7 win-3 win-4 win-8"></div>
    <div class="sq sq-8 win-3 win-5"></div>
    <div class="sq sq-9 win-3 win-6 win-7"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Uses classes:

```
$('.sq').on('click', function() {
  var currentPlayer = "player-x";
  if (!$(this).hasClass("player-x")
    && !$(this).hasClass("player-o") {
    $(this).addClass(currentPlayer);
    if (currentPlayer == "player-x")
      currentPlayer = "player-o";
    else
      currentPlayer = "player-x";
  }
}
```

Then a simple loop:

```
for var(var winIndex = 1; winIndex < 9; winIndex++){
  var selector = ".win-" + winIndex.toString();
  var x = $(select + ".player-x");
  var y = $(select + ".player-o");
  if (x.length == 3)
    // player x won
  if (y.length == 3)
    // player o won

  $('.board').addClass('winner-' + winIndex.toString());
}
```

Maybe add some CSS to automate X's and O's.

```
.sq.player-x::{
  content: "X"
}
.sq.player-o::{
  content: "O"
}
```

Could get fancy when someone wins with CSS.

```
#board.winner-1 .win-1{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to use that many classes though? Check the updated fiddle again and let me know if you believe this is a good code. https://jsfiddle.net/payam10/6qzu7L4f/11/

Comment: I personally have not read anything about *too many classes*.  Class names are second only to Ids as far as speed goes, so using data attributes for selectors is slow (and can actually be wrong).

Comment: Oh ok makes sense. Were you able to check my code? Thoughts/concerns?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to set for each cell an unique class, representing some line. There are h (horizontal), v (vertical) and d (diagonal) lines.

HTML code:

```
<div id="board">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sq h1 v1 d1"></div>
    <div class="sq h1 v2"></div>
    <div class="sq h1 v3 d2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sq h2 v1"></div>
    <div class="sq h2 v2 d1 d2"></div>
    <div class="sq h2 v3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sq h3 v1 d2"></div>
    <div class="sq h3 v2"></div>
    <div class="sq h3 v3 d1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code searches full lines for last marked cell. It takes cell's classes and checks corresponding lines.

```
var counter = 0;

$('.sq').on('click', function () {
  var current_cell = $(this);
  if (!current_cell.html().length) {
    var current_symbol = counter % 2 === 0 ? '0' : 'X';
    current_cell.html(current_symbol);

    if (counter >= 4) {
      var class_list = current_cell.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
      var index = 0;
      var winner = false;
      while (!winner && index < class_list.length) {
        var class_name = class_list[index];
        if ('sq' !== class_name) {
          var line = $('.' + class_name);
          var cell_index = 0;
          winner = true;
          while (winner && cell_index < line.length) {
            var cell = line.eq(cell_index);
            if (current_symbol != cell.html()) {
              winner = false;
            }
            cell_index++;
          }
        }
        index++;
      }
      if (winner) {
        line.css({'background-color': 'red'});
        $('.sq').off('click');
        alert(current_symbol + ' wins!');
      }
    }
    counter++;
  }
});
```